# GCP M1 and M2 CPUs not updating after approved quota request

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to create an M1 or M2 instance, but quotas doesn't update even if approved.

I have already CPUs (all regions) set to 120, CPUs for the region is 96, but when I make a request to increase quota for M1 or M2 CPUs to 40, I get an email that says that the increase has been approved, and it's been changed to these limits:

> |       Name       | Region | Requested Limit |
>
> | CPUS_ALL_REGIONS | GLOBAL |        40       |

But CPUs all regions doesn't change, and neither does M1 or M2.

Comment: This has happened to me. I completed the quota increase form again and mentioned that the increase was approved but not applied.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, tried but same error. I don't think anyone read the message because it's approved within a minute.

Comment: Ask for a giant quota and then explain in the details section. Maybe open a billing support case.

Comment: Update: They said after reviewing my case, to contact my sales representative, not sure if they mean that my quota increase request had been rejected (even if I got a confirmation email) or that they just thought it had been rejected and there is some other "bug" at play.

Comment: When you create resources in the cloud, the cloud vendor is basically granting you credit. As you begin to use more resources and more expensive resources, credit/risk becomes an item to manage. Basically, you are requested to work with sales so that they can establish a larger amount of credit. Fairly typical in the business world.

Comment: I talked with a sales representative, he did know why I got a confirmation message if the quota increase was rejected, but he could help me in contact with someone who can increase my quotas (after reviewing my case).